# Python sudoku puzzle solver doesn't display puzzle correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to write up a Sudoku puzzle solver, and so far, I'm stuck on trying to get it to display the puzzle. Here is my code so far:

```
class Cell:
'''A cell for the soduku game.'''
def __init__(self):
    #This is our constructor
    self.__done = False #We are not finished at the start
    self.__answer = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) #Here is the tuple containing all of our possibilities
    self.__setnum = 8 #This will be used later when we set the number.
def __str__(self):
    '''This formats what the cell returns.'''
    answer = 'This cell can be: '
    answer += str(self.__answer) #This pulls our answer from our tuple
    return answer
def get_possible(self):
    '''This tells us what our possibilities exist.'''
    answer = ()
    return self.__answer
def is_done(self):
    '''Does a simple check on a variable to determine if we are done.'''
    return self.__done
def remove(self, number):
    '''Removes a possibility from the possibility tuple.'''
    if number == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9: #Checks if we have a valid answer
        temp = list(self.__answer) #Here is the secret: We change the tuple to a list, which we can easily modify, and than turn it back.
        temp.remove(number)
        self.__answer = tuple(temp)
def set_number(self, number):
    '''Removes all but one possibility from the possibility tuple. Also sets "__done" to true.'''
    answer = 8
    for num in self.__answer:
        if num == number:
            answer = number #Checks if the number is in the tuple, and than sets that value as the tuple, which becomes an integer.
    self.__answer = answer
    self.__done = True
    return self.__answer
```

That is for the cells, and here is the code for the grid:

```
class Grid:
'''The grid for the soduku game.'''
def __init__(self, puzzle):
    '''Constructs the soduku puzzle from the file.'''
    self.__file = open(puzzle)
    self.__puzzle = ''
    self.__template = '   |   |   \n   |   |   \n   |   |   \n   |   |   \n   |   |   \n   |   |   \n   |   |   \n   |   |   \n   |   |   \n'
    for char in self.__file:
        if char == '.':
            self.__puzzle += ' '
        else:
            self.__puzzle += char
    count = 0
    self.__template_list = list(self.__template)
    for char in self.__puzzle:
        if char != '|':
            if char == '.' or ' ':
                self.__template_list[count] = ' '
            else:
                self.__template_list[count] = char
    self.__answer = ''
    for char in self.__template_list:
        self.__answer += char
    self.__file.close()
def __str__(self):
    '''Prints the soduku puzzle nicely.'''
    return self.__answer
```

When I try to print it, I get two vertical lines of pipes (|). Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: But there are two pipes between each number inf your `template`?

Comment: Could you, please, show some output.

Comment: please don't use `__` in front of everything unless you _need_ mangling

Comment: Seems like `count` is never incremented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is really hard to read. You should separate your problem into subproblems and structure them more logically.

But to answer your question directly, in line 7 you're assigning an empty template to `self.__template`. In line 14 you're converting the template to a list of characters (why? after all you're not writing to it) and assign it to `self.__template_list`. Finally in lines 21 to 23 you're iterating over the list of template characters (which is still empty) and append it to `self.__answer`, which you print in `__str__()`. Thus you get just the pipes.

Maybe I can give you some hints as to how to improve your code:

1. The textual representation of the grid should be irrelevant to the general concept of the grid and thus should not concern most of the methods of your Grid class. In your case, it's littering the `__init__()` method and it makes it hard to understand what the method actually does. You could do several operations with your grid that don't need to know how the grid is displayed in the end (if at all).

   The code to output your grid should be completely confined to the method which is responsible for that, in your case `__str__()`.
2. For variables that are irrelevant to other methods or the users of the class, use local variables instead of member variables. Unnecessary member variables make your code harder to understand, less efficient and confuse you when debugging, when inspecting the instance members with `dir()`, for instance.
3. Think of a data structure that more logically represents your grid (and that contains only the necessary data, not superfluous details for representation). I suggest a list of lists, since that's very easy to manipulate in python (you could also use a two-dimensional numpy array, for instance).

I suggest something akin to this:

```
class Grid:
    '''The grid for the soduku game.'''

    def __init__(self, puzzle):
        '''Constructs the soduku puzzle from the file.'''

        self.grid = []

        with open(puzzle, "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                # strip CR/LF, replace . by space, make a list of chars
                self.grid.append([" " if char in " ." else char for char in line.rstrip("\r\n")])

    def __str__(self):
        '''Prints the soduku puzzle nicely.'''

        lines = []

        for i, row in enumerate(self.grid):
            if i != 0 and i % 3 == 0:
                # add a separator every 3 lines
                lines.append("+".join(["-" * 3] * 3))

            # add a separator every 3 chars
            line = "|".join(map("".join, zip(*([iter(row)] * 3))))
            lines.append(line)

        lines.append("")

        return "\n".join(lines)
```

Note that this version expects a file with a very rigid format (no separation lines or chars, exact number of chars per line). You can practise improving it to read more liberal formats.

Also note that the only member variable I used is `self.grid`. All other variables are local to the respective function.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong (it will always be True)

```
if number == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9:
```

use

```
if 1 <= number <= 9:
```

This is also wrong

```
for char in self.__file:
    if char == '.':
        self.__puzzle += ' '
    else:
        self.__puzzle += char
```

Iterating over a file yields *lines* not characters.

I'd suggest that you write and test your code in smaller parts. Put some `print`s in there to make sure the code is doing what you expect it to.

Comment: Or use `if number in range(1, 10)` if you want to ensure that it looks for integer value.